# objective C FCM how to get remote message when app in background

Tags: objective-c, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

my code can get remote notification and remote message, the last problem is can not getting remote message when app in background ( just open app then got it)

- When i push remote notification and app in background, it's seem notification message show like expect, click to this notification then it bring me to my app. I dont know why remote message does not have some behavior like that( I using postman and "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send" to send remote message)

  . Plz someone help me
  Here is my code

  ```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
      // Register for remote notifications
      if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
          // iOS 7.1 or earlier. Disable the deprecation warnings.
          UIRemoteNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
          (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
           UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
           UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge);
          [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:allNotificationTypes];

      } else {
          // iOS 8 or later
          // [START register_for_notifications]
          if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
              UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
              (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
              UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
              [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
              [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
          } else {
              // iOS 10 or later
    UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
              UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
              | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
              | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
              [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
               requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions
               completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
               }
               ];

              // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
              [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];
              // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
              [[FIRMessaging messaging] setRemoteMessageDelegate:self];
          }

          [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
          // [END register_for_notifications]
      }

      // [START configure_firebase]
      [FIRApp configure];
      // [END configure_firebase]
      // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshNotification:)
                                                   name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];

      return YES;
  }

  // [START receive_message]
  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
      // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
      // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
      // TODO: Handle data of notification

      // Print message ID.
      NSLog(@"didReceiveRemoteNotification1 ID: %@", userInfo[@"gcm.message_id"]);

      // Print full message.
      NSLog(@"didReceiveRemoteNotification1 %@", userInfo);
  }

  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
  fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
      // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
      // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
      // TODO: Handle data of notification

      // Print message ID.
      NSLog(@"didReceiveRemoteNotification2 ID: %@", userInfo[@"gcm.message_id"]);

      // Print full message.
      NSLog(@"didReceiveRemoteNotification2 %@", userInfo);
  }
  - (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
         willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
           withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {
      // Print message ID.
      NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;
      NSLog(@"willPresentNotification: %@", userInfo[@"gcm.message_id"]);

      // Print full message.
      NSLog(@"willPresentNotification %@", userInfo);
  }

  - (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
  didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
           withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
      NSDictionary *userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo;
      NSLog(@"didReceiveNotificationResponse: %@", userInfo);
  }

  - (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
      NSLog(@"%@", [remoteMessage appData]);
      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [remoteMessage appData]] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
      [alert show];
  }
  - (void)tokenRefreshNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {

      NSString *refreshedToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
      NSLog(@"InstanceID token: %@", refreshedToken);
      [self connectToFcm];
  }
  - (void)connectToFcm {
      [[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
          if (error != nil) {
              NSLog(@"Unable to connect to FCM. %@", error);
          } else {
              NSLog(@"Connected to FCM.");
          }
      }];
  }
  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
      NSLog(@"Unable to register for remote notifications: %@", error);
  }
  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
      NSLog(@"APNs token retrieved: %@", deviceToken);
      [[FIRMessaging messaging] setAPNSToken:deviceToken];
  }

  - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
      [self connectToFcm];
  }

  - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
      [[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];
      NSLog(@"Disconnected from FCM");
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

For other people who face same problem.

Finally after a lot of searching, i found the solution, very simple, u need to follow the content of firebase app message to make it readable by push notification service. U can see [here](https://medium.com/developermind/using-firebase-cloud-messaging-for-remote-notifications-in-ios-d35de1dc67b2) 
and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support)

this is sample to make it show to device when in background mode :)

```
{
  "condition": "'condition1' in topics && 'condition2' in topics",
  "notification": {
      "category": "notification_category",
      "title_loc_key": "notification_title",
      "body_loc_key": "notification_body",
      "badge": 1
  },
  "data": {
    "data_type": "notification_data_type",
    "data_id": "111111",
    "data_detail": "FOO",
    "data_detail_body": "BAR"
  }
}
```

Now everything work like expect, then the second job is just modify message content like whatever u want :)